# Every site requesting verification that I'm human

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, cloudflare

I keep several (many) tabs for SE sites open on a continuous basis. Over the past couple of days, every time I refresh the questions, I'm getting the intercept page that checks the security of my connection and asks me to verify that I'm human. This is happening regardless of site, and approximately every five minutes, or every time I look at the question page for a site that I'm not a member of. Why?

[image: Example of Captcha page that intercepts everything]

<strike>*Addendum: This may be related to something in Chrome/Edge (I'm using Chrome); I don't seem to be seeing the issue with FireFox 117*</strike> No, it's happening with Firefox, too.

Comment: Is this page hosted on Stack Exchange? Can you post the URL and/or screenshot of it, please?

Comment: (if not part of SE, well, this is off topic here, it's something on your side)

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard - pic added. When it appears on another site, the site name is reflected in the first line (e.g., Superuser.com, rpg.stackexchange.com, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, odd indeed. Looks like you somehow fell victim to the "new" anti DDoS system described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243006/152859). Maybe your IP address is shared with some known spammer, so if you can change it, try it.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard - can't; this is a government agency network; our computers are NATted for public internet access. I have no idea what my public IP address is, and couldn't change it even if I did, as it's handled by the NATter.

Comment: Also might be case of too many requests, which happens when some userscript(s) going rogue, so try to disable all of them. Though in such case, you should get different error.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard - N/A in this case; I have no userscripts.

Comment: ahh, I forgot for a second the [cause for most recent bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393039/stack-exchange-network-sites-ip-addresses-may-change-in-the-coming-weeks). (I mean bugs from today, since they started actually changing the IP address)

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard - Problem started yesterday for me, in the afternoon (NYC). Can't see it being frequency, as I didn't refresh at all between about 16:00 yesterday and 07:30 today.

Comment: hmm... see [this](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/stuck-on-the-checking-if-the-site-connection-is-secure/478778/2) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/CloudFlare/comments/zy25i7/cloudflare_checking_if_the_site_connection_is/), some answers there might be useful to you as well.

Comment: Apologies for this - I've escalated it internally and we're investigating what's going on. Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: @Catija while at it, [another one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393122/new-cloudflare-protection-breaking-important-bots), probably same root issue.

Comment: @Catija - as of 9/21 I'm seeing it again, but only on [Su].

Comment: @Catija - and on Meta - but not on SO.

Comment: @Catija - and on other sites. Basically, yesterday's/Tuesday's fix seems to have been temporary only. The only site I haven't seen it on is SO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! This is related to the recent announcement - [Stack Exchange network sites’ IP addresses may change in the coming weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393039/stack-exchange-network-sites-ip-addresses-may-change-in-the-coming-weeks) - so it's on our end, not yours!

As you've discovered, we've implemented new bot protections to help protect the site better. We're actively adjusting the detection rules to prevent this kind of thing and have just rolled out a fix that should hopefully resolve the issue.

Please let us know if you're still having any issues.

We will be monitoring meta for other reports like this and have asked mods to be on the lookout for these bugs so we can address them quickly. Thanks so much for your patience as we complete this migration.

Comment: It does look like it's fixed; if it continues to appear fixed tomorrow, I'll accept this answer with thanks.

Comment: OK, after leaving 35 SE tabs up overnight on each of Chrome and Firefox, and not getting a single request for human verification this morning when I refreshed each of those tabs, I'm going to say "Yeah, it's fixed!" Thanks for your help on this, and for keeping the community informed.

Comment: [Sloshy failed last night](https://github.com/tripleee/sloshy/issues/65) with a hitherto unfamiliar 403 error, I expect anything which uses ChatExchange will have the same problem if indeed this is because of the CAPTCHA.

Comment: This has become unfixed as of Thursday afternoon (NYC). I am now getting this on SU and sites other than SO.

Comment: I think I faced pretty much the same issue https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426549/oauth2-not-working

Comment: We're still fine tuning the config and have made more changes to hopefully get even less false positives.