# New Cloudflare protection breaking important bots

Tags: bug, chat, captcha, chatbot, cloudflare

Something about SE's DDoS protection or human verification must have changed, which has caused several important chatbots to no longer be able to log in.

At first, `curl`ing `/users/login` from my home IP address worked, and a bot hosted there could log in just fine, while a bot of mine running on a cloud server couldn't log in and going to `/users/login` with `curl` or an incognito browser tab led to a Cloudflare CAPTCHA page.

After moving the bot (New Posts/Sandbox Posts, which is used both by CGCC's and PLDI's main rooms for moderation purposes) to my home server, the same CAPTCHA'ing/`403` issue started showing up, which will potentially impact other bots running on the same server.

This is definitely new behavior, and it seems like it will result in significant headaches for chatbot designers.

Comment: This is probably related to [the problem that I reported earlier today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393116/every-site-requesting-verification-that-im-human)...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Likely caused by the same thing yeah. Hopefully they'll fix this soon since it seems to be impacting both bots and real users

Comment: Well at least Snowpaw is alive. :D

Comment: We've got a fix for your specific case coming soon but this fix won't necessarily prevent others from having similar issues - which may require some discussion internally. Thanks for the report!

Comment: While the specific situation is different than @JeffZeitlin's post, the core issue is the same, so I've marked them as a duplicates as this should also be fixed now - for you at least. As with any bug reports, please feel free to open new bug reports if you are still experiencing issues. Thanks for your patience as we work through this migration!