# Occasionally getting "502 Bad Gateway" errors from Cloudflare when trying to view SE questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, cloudflare

Over the past several days, when clicking on multiple SE questions from a list in relatively rapid succession to open them into new tabs, I've occasionally (1 question among around every 25 on average, although sometimes more often, such as today) been getting the error shown below:

> [image: 504 Bad Gateway error from Cloudflare]

For example, when I opened about 15 Mathematics SE questions from a list today, 3 of them had this error. Note that I've done similar actions (i.e., opening multiple questions from a list) literally thousands of times before during the previous almost 5 years, with this error never appearing until just a few days ago.

Fortunately, the questions (and any answers) have *always* (at least, they have so far) been displayed properly after I've refreshed the screen, so it's just a relatively minor nuisance for me. Nonetheless, I'm reporting this because other people may be getting this more often, a refresh may not always work each time for them, and this issue may help to determine, and perhaps also solve, some more important underlying problem.

FWIW, I'm using a plain version (i.e., no scripts, plugins, etc.) of Edge on Windows 10. Also, I suspect this is occurring due to what [Stack Exchange network sites’ IP addresses may change in the coming weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393039) describes, with other possibly related questions being [New Cloudflare protection breaking important bots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393122) and [Cloudflare blocks Archive.org from saving network profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393231).

Comment: Also noticed this happen yesterday, but *only on Edge* (for me, at least).  I mostly use Vivaldi for browsing SE sites, and I haven't seen this problem there in hundreds of posts in the last few days.

Comment: 502 shouldn't be due to CloudFlare protections, those should get a 4xx series response. I just tested opening 20 tabs within 30 seconds on Edge and couldn't reproduce this, will check the logs to see if I can find anything.

Comment: @JoshZhang Thanks for your attention, the extra details, and that you'll check the logs. Regarding the speed of opening tabs from Edge, I haven't timed myself, but I often do it rather quickly, with it fairly often being more than 1 tab per second on average. Nonetheless, I'm not sure to what extent, if any, my speed is a factor, as this problem hasn't yet occurred often enough, or in any particular pattern that I've been able to discern.

Comment: After digging through the logs I suspect this is due to the IP cutover and DNS TTL. We're still getting some stragglers trying to point the the old IP address which could be what's causing this issue. This should go away once all the DNS records point to our new IP address.

Comment: @JohnOmielan sounds good, I'll mark this as status-completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the past more than 3 days since I originally posted this, I've opened over 500 questions from question lists into separate tabs, with varying batch sizes and average speed of question opening per batch, but with no errors, including the 502 one, occurring at all. This indicates to me that the problem was likely only temporary, with this being consistent with [Josh Zhang's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393283/occasionally-getting-502-bad-gateway-errors-from-cloudflare-when-trying-to-vie#comment1315541_393283):

> After digging through the logs I suspect this is due to the IP cutover and DNS TTL. We're still getting some stragglers trying to point the the old IP address which could be what's causing this issue. This should go away once all the DNS records point to our new IP address.

Thus, unless and until I get any indication otherwise, I consider this problem to be resolved.