# Cloudflare protection is triggering on Stack Overflow authentication API routes

Tags: bug, status-review, api, captcha, authentication

The Stack Overflow OAuth endpoints (`https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/` and `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json`) have started responding to requests from the server I run my projects on with 403s and a Cloudflare CAPTCHA page, meaning users are unable to log in. This issue seems very similar to [New Cloudflare protection breaking important bots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393122/new-cloudflare-protection-breaking-important-bots).

Comment: Oddly, using `wget` to manually POST to the endpoints (from the same server) and providing a browser UA works correctly, returning a JSON error.

Comment: Feels similar to this: https://stackapps.com/questions/10497/suddenly-getting-couldnt-parse-client-id/10498#10498

Comment: A UserAgent that is long enough is needed, indeed.

Comment: New report on Stack Apps as well: https://stackapps.com/questions/10513/stackexchange-oauth2-0-is-suddenly-failing

Comment: This appears to have expanded to the rest of the site as well, unfortunately. I've contacted SE personally, but haven't gotten a response yet.

Comment: Yeah, I status-reviewed the reports on Stack Apps already. Let me check if an MSE mod is  around to discuss if adding more status-review tags will help.

Comment: I've been informed that the dev-team has the tickets on their board, I've not been given an ETA so it remains a waiting game.

Comment: Almost "me too!" I have the same problem but with a new personal project. In the meantime, when this issue is solved, I'm experimenting with Auth0. So far, it's working fine for my use case.

Comment: Possibly related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398192/bot-is-unable-to-access-site-from-github-actions