# Cloudflare CAPTCHA for Tor Browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, cloudflare, tor

I'm living in a country where it is illegal to access the internet. Thanks to the Tor browser we can access the internet freely. Before today, it was possible to access this website with the Tor browser. Now it is not possible no matter how much I try. I get a CAPTCHA from Cloudflare that says verifying ... , and no matter how much I click on that I'm a human button. Please make it normal and work like it used to.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, new protection layers. Details in the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393116/every-site-requesting-verification-that-im-human).

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Im using tor browser due to government restrictions , i will never gonna access this website anymore , thanks to the new cloudflare guy ...

Comment: It's still ongoing process, they might put exception in place to allow Tor access.

Comment: Can you clarify your question - you said you can't get past the CAPTCHA but you posted this question here. Are you unable to complete the CAPTCHA or are you seeing them more frequently than previously? I'm trying to better understand what you're experiencing so we can make recommendations for you.

Comment: @Catija as i said clearly ,  i can't pass the captcha in TOR browser because accessing the internet is illegal in this country , and yet im using firefox to send this post and there is a possibility for me to get arrested or executed , so i need to use Tor browser to access the internet , but it seems like its working for now , maybe the cloudflare guy get fired who knows ...

Comment: @hamed.3d172 I think Catija reasonably assumed that your government blocks your connection if it is illegal. After all, why would you have the opportunity to access the internet if the goverment doesn't allow it. Anyways, I think your question was clear, but Catija just wanted to clear up that possible source of confusion for everyone reading.

Comment: @Catija This is a well-known issue with Cloudflare: Cloudflare uses hCaptcha and hCaptcha doesn't work; and Cloudflare's super-secret “decide who's legit” algorithm is pretty discriminatory. (I'm kinda surprised _I_ can still access Stack Exchange.) Though I think there are modes you can set Cloudflare to that mitigate these issues.

Comment: @Catija Nope ! still getting cloudflare , im living in iran if you may wanted to know , i can access Youtube , twitter and facebook via TOR , stackexchange and reddit are frequently getting blocked by the government you can research it by your self , there is a high chance for me not to be able to visit this website forever only because of CF , i really hate them at this point

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks for your patience while we looked into this situation - it sounds like it's been very stressful for you. Our intention is not to prevent TOR access on our sites generally. After raising this issue internally with the team supporting this change, they adjusted our CAPTCHA settings so that normal access patterns should not lead to challenges.

Since this change went live, we've seen a huge decrease in challenges on our end, so hopefully it has addressed the issue for you. If not, please let us know.

Comment: So , it seems like that after i posted the question here i can access stackxchange for now , unlike instagram this forum got the kindest and the best members and staff ever existed in one place thank you alot . but just imagine if i couldn't post this question , i would and the rest of my country blacked out from this place for ever currently CF is blocking our access to many sites like artstation instagram etc i really hate them ...

Comment: Disliking Cloudflare is going to become increasingly stressful as they host an ever larger fraction of the world's most popular sites. I can understand your frustration, but there aren't many alternatives, and many site owners are _extremely_ satisfied with Cloudflare. (I agree that the "human verification" notice is disruptive and annoying, even to those of us for whom it basically never fails.)

Comment: @tripleee having a working human verification isn't bad im not against that , but havin a non working human verification is nonsense it is completely blocks a group of peoples access to the world , also if the whole internet goes under someone like cloudflare , governments can bribe them for example to avoid people access to the internet from a region for example youtube and other free social medias , this is slavery ...

Comment: Some more insight regarding CloudFlare, they're merely offering a service to protect web sites from bots, on top of their normal CDN offering. It's ultimately up to their customers to set and fine tune the filters so that the Captcha are presented to as few real users as possible. You can even turn it off all together if desired. That is to say CloudFlare shouldn't draw all the blame in this situation.

Comment: @JoshZhang the cloudflare guy is back im getting cloudflare again ... i guess were vanishing slowly by these companies ....