# Cloudflare blocks Archive.org from saving network profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile, archive, cloudflare

While [saving a regular question page to Archive.org seems to work](https://web.archive.org/web/20230922111110/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216143/origin-url-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin), when I try to save a network profile page, I'm either getting an error before saving the page "The capture failed because Save Page Now does not have access rights for https://stackexchange.com/users/7562599/laurel (HTTP status=403)" or an error after saving the page ([example 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20230922111832/https://stackexchange.com/web/20230922111832/https://stackexchange.com/users/7562599/laurel?tab=activity), [example 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20230922111236/https://stackexchange.com/web/20230922111236/https://stackexchange.com/users/201110/shadow-the-gpt-wizard)):

> ### stackexchange.com
>
> stackexchange.com needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.
>
> Ray ID: 80a9b96c6ca6cf05
> Performance & security by Cloudflare

The network profile page is really handy to save for moderation purposes, because it has links to every post or comment a (non-prolific) user has made across SE. As a workaround, I'm using [Archive.today](https://archive.ph/) but that seems to be less well known (and also is less trusted).

A related, but fixed issue (see also its duplicates): [Every site requesting verification that I'm human](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393116/323179)

Comment: It's also not possible to [save network flairs](https://web.archive.org/save/https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/6085540.png) and I notice my scripts have a hard time reaching certain URLs like https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-json too

Comment: @Glorfindel I've created an explicit report for the hot-questions-json: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393242/hot-network-questions-feed-app-no-longer-working

Comment: I've pushed a change that will hopefully fix this, please test when able, thanks!

Comment: @JoshZhang I still got "The capture failed because Save Page Now does not have access rights for https://stackexchange.com/users/7562599/laurel (HTTP status=403)."

Comment: @Laurel created a bypass that just went live. That challenge shouldn't be there any more.

Comment: @JoshZhang Maybe that 403 is cached since I'm getting the same error. Another page seems to have successfully saved, however.

Comment: Could be cache, should be working everywhere since I pushed the change out. Our rate limiters however are going through CF now so you'll also get the verification page if you go over our rate limits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apologies for the issues, I dug in further late Friday and found another bug and made a change to resolve it. You should not receive any more 403 responses moving forward.