# Human Verification Broken Again

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, cloudflare

The fix implemented in response to [my previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393116/every-site-requesting-verification-that-im-human) has broken, and I'm getting requests to re-verify if I refresh after five minutes.
It happens only once (each five minutes) for any `*.stackexchange.com` site, and an additional request for Super User (and presumably any other SE site that has its own domain name, except for Stack Overflow). I'm using the same computer and network that I was when I posted my previous question; I don't rule out that my public IP has changed - but it should still be in the same allocation.

Comment: Hey, I saw your comment - we've made some further adjustments. :)

Comment: @Catija - Still no change - every five minutes for `*.stackexchange.com`, separately for Super User, not at all for Stack Overflow. And if the five minutes expires while I'm writing a question, answer, or comment, I can't post it until I refresh, get the verification, and rewrite/paste.

Comment: I pushed a change half an hour ago in response to this report https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393231/cloudflare-blocks-archive-org-from-saving-network-profiles?noredirect=1#comment1315195_393231 should have fixed it.

Comment: I'll try to verify from home over the weekend; if I don't get the chance, or the results are inconclusive, I'll comment here on Tuesday. Thanks.

Comment: OK, after a few refreshes of all umpty-twelve SE tabs, Cloudflare is currently not bugging me, so it's tentatively "fixed" for now...

Comment: Good to hear, I've been monitoring the logs and tweaking things behind the scene. Will mark this as status-completed.

Comment: @JoshZhang hi, looks like [it's happening again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394161/many-sites-dont-render-correctly-static-assets-cannot-be-downloaded).