# Hot Network Questions Feed App no longer working

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions, error-message, cloudflare

The app I created to offer [RSS feeds from Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-json) fails since today to fetch its data from the source.

One of its main endpoints is [`https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-json`](https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-json)<sup>1</sup>. It looks like the app now gets blocked by the CloudFlare anti-bot measures.

These are the headers of the error response I've captured:

```json
{
  date: 'Fri, 22 Sep 2023 15:48:49 GMT',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'content-length': '6440',
  connection: 'close',
  'cross-origin-embedder-policy': 'require-corp',
  'cross-origin-opener-policy': 'same-origin',
  'cross-origin-resource-policy': 'same-origin',
  'origin-agent-cluster': '?1',
  'permissions-policy': 'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),browsing-topics=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()',
  'referrer-policy': 'same-origin',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'cf-mitigated': 'challenge',
  'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, ' +
    'must-revalidate, post-check=0, ' +
    'pre-check=0',
  expires: 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT',
  'set-cookie': [
    '__cf_bm=plX85fIOvG4mmOUx57Q1e0XfZBxw.EXY2uutj8wExP0-1695397729-0-Ae7cVUGXTf7+Y1VxTBV4vFPpB0eFfxvXJJ3fyC8EZkoi2WPMuGCWbZnLXvowMpONw8ed2sVpy2ZyLUo5XkHbhE0=; ' +
      'path=/; expires=Fri, 22-Sep-23 16:18:49 GMT; ' +
      'domain=.stackexchange.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None'
  ],
  'x-dns-prefetch-control': 'off',
  server: 'cloudflare',
  'cf-ray': '80abb1c15868380c-IAD'
}
```

And the start of the HTML body:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title>
```

I do note that several chat rooms across the network rely on the app to get informed on a timely basis of new Hot Network Questions. The functionality for [RSS feeds on migrated posts](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/migrations) is not affected so far as that relies on the Stack Exchange API.

Can this be fixed by SE and/or mitigated by me? In the latter case I'm happy to make changes that works for you.

Just a moment ... (6 to 8 weeks?)

---

<sub>1. The endpoint was part of the mobile infrastructure but [it was decided to not decommission that specific endpoint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383125).</sub>

Comment: If this is better served as an answer on one of the many other reports, ie: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393116/every-site-requesting-verification-that-im-human, I'm happy to move it. So far it seems that for each unique cloudflare hick-up a separate bug exists. I don't mind how the reports are bundled or tracked, as long as the underlying issue gets addressed.

Comment: I made some adjustments from this report, should fix your issue also. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393231/cloudflare-blocks-archive-org-from-saving-network-profiles?noredirect=1#comment1315195_393231

Comment: @JoshZhang yes, that solved the issue! You're awesome, thanks for the work you've put into this. It is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for your patience as we adjust things during the transition. I've made what I hope is the change that should resolve all the current Captcha issues that everyone has been getting.