# I can't answer a question because there's no captcha

Tags: bug, captcha

I want to answer a question, but there's no captcha present. I tried reloading the page, and I even tried a different browser. Still no captcha.

[Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/781488/motional-emf-and-faraday-law)'s the question, in case it matters.

It's been a while since I answered an SE question, so I'm not sure what is supposed to happen. After clicking 'Post Your Answer', I was seeing an alert saying I couldn't post because I hadn't answered the captcha. I'm not sure at what point I should have been prompted.

I wanted to add a screenshot, but, oddly, after I posted this question I tried again to answer another question. I clicked the Answer button and my answer went through without prompting me for a Captcha. Needless to say, I can no longer get a screenshot.

Comment: Sounds like a dumb question but... what does a no captcha present look like? There's some work going on with a migration that might affect this

Comment: An (***[annotated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)***) screenshot would make sense. (Preferably with a frame if the background colour is also white.)

Comment: This might be related to [my own report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393231/323179), since there was no CAPTCHA there either. Are you on a special network, like behind a work or country firewall?

Comment: Oddly, after I posted this question I tried again to answer the other question.  I clicked the Answer button and my answer went through without prompting me for a Captcha.  Needless to say, I can no longer get a screenshot.

Comment: It's been a while since I answered a SE question, so I'm not sure what is supposed to happen.  After clicking Post Your Answer, I was seeing an alert saying I couldn't post because I hadn't answered the captcha.  I'm not sure at what point I should have been prompted.

Comment: If you type up an answer (or question) and then let it sit for too long (let's say 24 hours) and then try to post it, you can reliably trigger a CAPTCHA. Try it in the sandbox.